# Values are missing only when select records in Excel VBA script

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

*edit

I didn't find any solution so I separate the sql queries and it works(ugly but works) if anyone have a good solution i'd like to see

.....................................................................................................................................................

When I select records in SQL Server Management Studio I get some values that when I select with the same query in Excel VBA script I don't get some of them

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim conn As New Connection, rec As New Recordset
    Dim comm As New Command
    Set comm.ActiveConnection = conn

    conNum = "123"
    
    comm.CommandText = _
    "SELECT A.xyz, A.style, A.color, " & _
        "B.vessel_name, B.location, B.importnum_id, A.warehouse, " & _
        "A.qty1, A.qty2, A.qty " & _
    "FROM Wf20.dbo.A A, Wf20.dbo.B B " & _
    "WHERE '" & conNum & "' = A.xyz AND " & _
        "B.fileno = A.fileno AND " & _
        "A.importnum_id = B.importnum_id"
        
    Debug.Print comm.CommandText
    rec.Open comm

    Do While Not rec.EOF
      If rec("qty") > 0 Then
         SomeFunc rec
      End If
      
      rec.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub

Sub SomeFunc(recS As Recordset)
    rec("style") ' same as sql manager
    rec("color") ' same as sql manager
    rec("qty") ' same as sql manager
    rec("qty1") ' same as sql manager
    rec("importnum_id") ' empty just here
    rec("warehouse") ' empty just here  
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea why can it happen?

*after debug I found that without the `If qty > 0` there was more values not empty (there is only one record in the db in my case and the qty is bigger than 0) now I'm really confused

Comment: (Possible) side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: it just for inner users not for public i didnt secure the app from sql injection

Comment: "it just for inner users..." -- Doesn't excuse anything! Always do it the *right* way! Never trust any users input. An "inner user" might become an attacker too. Or used by one. Or simply put in garbage by accident.

Comment: you're right. but I needed it urgently so it's temporary just to send the excel records

Comment: Also not an excuse...

Comment: Posted SQL is not valid?  (ends with `AND`), and your VBA would not work either, so it doesn't give us much idea what you're actually doing.   Are you saying you paste the `Debug.Print` output and run it and the results are different?  Why types of field are the ones with missing values?

Comment: If you trust your users to 1 Not be dumb and 2. Not be malicious, you are gravely mistaken. Just because someone must already be authenticated into your domain doesn't mean they can be trusted. I am reminded of this far too frequently.

Comment: And SQL injection is just as much about *correctness* as about *security*. It's also nearly always more performant. Always always use parameters

Comment: @Larnu it just for me i don't trust anybody after i just send the excel records

Comment: @TimWilliams the AND was mistake just over here. and yes i paste the debug.print in sql manager

Comment: Still not an excuse. @EbayEliav . Unless you are teaching someone the dangers of SQL Injection there is no excuse to write your queries where the parameters are (insecurely) injected. Parametrise your parameters and your question don't get derailed by people telling you to secure your code.

Comment: How many records in the results set ? Is it the same number for both methods ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes. one record in the recordset and in the sql manager. it seems that after i access to the recordset some values are disappear

Comment: What do you get if you dump the recordset to a sheet with `Sheet3.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rec` immediately after `rec.Open comm`

Comment: @CDP1802 even less data after the first null value there is no more values

Comment: Which fields have nulls in, is it importnum_id ?

Comment: @CDP1802 no. veesel_name. and also the importnum_id field is not the id of the table. now i add rec.moveFirst and there is more values but not all of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238561/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-ebay-eliav).